# Cannot find library to run Google Cloud ML Engine Keras model (ta-lib)

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, keras, google-cloud-ml, ta-lib

I'm trying to run a keras model on Google Cloud ML Engine but it does not run because it cannot find a dependency. Namely, it's [TA-lib](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib). The error is as follows:

```
talib/common.c:242:28: fatal error: ta-lib/ta_defs.h: No such file or directory
```

The install_requires in my setup.py file looks like this:

```
setup(name='dnd31',
  version='0.1',
  packages=find_packages(),
  description='example to run keras on gcloud ml-engine',
  author='me',
  author_email='author@example.com',
  license='MIT',
  install_requires=[
      'keras',
      'h5py',
       'pandas',
       'ta-lib',
       'TA-Lib'],
  zip_safe=False)
```

I'm able to run it locally just fine. Is there a better way to include dependencies besides the setup.py file?